# Display overlay view between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, view, swift4

I am trying to display an overlay view on top of every ViewController after successfully logging in to show loading status of the app and load some data while this view is being displayed.
This view comes from a custom NIB file.

I display the OverlayLoadingView after a successful login request to the server, then I want to present a new ViewController on another Storyboard using:

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And finally hide the OverlayLoadingView in the next ViewController (This is why I handle it as a Singleton).

But when I present the next ViewController, the OverlayLoadingView disappears. Is there a way to display this loading view on top of everything while presenting a new view controller on the back at the same time?

Something like this:

LoginViewController -> Successfully logged in -> display OverlayView -> present MainViewController -> MainViewController presented below OverlayView -> Load initial data -> Hide OverlayView after initial data has been loaded.

```
@IBDesignable
public class OverlayLoadingView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var headerImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var detailTextLabel: UILabel!

    class var sharedInstance: OverlayLoadingView {
        struct Static {
            static let instance: OverlayLoadingView = OverlayLoadingView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    // Custom view from the XIB file
    fileprivate var view: UIView!
    // Set header image directly by giving a value to headerImageURL variable from server response

    /**
     Initialiser method
     */
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupNib()
    }

    /**
     Initialiser method
     */
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupNib()
    }

    fileprivate func loadNib() -> UIView? {
        return Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("OverlayLoadingView", owner:  self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView
    }

    func setupNib() {
        if let overlayLoadingView = loadNib() {
            self.view = overlayLoadingView

            let screenWidth = Util.screenSize().width
            let screenHeight = Util.screenSize().height
            self.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
            view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

            self.addSubview(view)
        }
    }

    public func showOverlay() {
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate,
            let window = appDelegate.window {

            self.alpha = 1.0
            window.addSubview(self)

            activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        }
    }

    public func hideOverlayView() {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

EDIT:

To display the overlay view I am using:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TabMenu", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
    OverlayLoadingView.sharedInstance.showOverlay()
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: {
         // Dismiss current VC?
    })
}
```

The views hierarchy is shown like the following image. The overlay view should be over everything.

[image: Views hierarchy]

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is to display the loading view above all controllers you can add the view to the window.

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
    let overlay = OverlayLoadingView(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
    overlay.tag = 1001
    window.addSubView(overlay)
    // remove it like this
    window.viewWithTag(overlay.tag)?.removeFromSuperView()

}
```

By the way this is not a Singleton as I'm able to use init and create another instance mark the init as private. Make the class final to avoid reflection and replace `class` with `static` As class can be overided but static can't.

Comment: Hello Amber, great answer btw. But I still have the same issue, even if I do not remove the view from its superView, the overlayView disappears when new view controller is presented.

Comment: It is a private app, so I can't share you the code. I just shared the "common" code on my question. I will edit my question to add the presenting code I am using. I have already include your code on my "showOverlay()" method.